# Pass callback to startActivityForResult without changing activity class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My problem that I need to get a cookie from my site. To solve this I have an API endpoint like `http://example.com/cookie` which redirects using app schema `myapp://cookie=some_cookie`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (goToBrowser) { // Going to url which redirects back to this activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
    } else { // Parcing incoming url
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I have an `Activity` which processes app schema. How can I get `some_cookie` if I can't change `appActivity` class?

**UPDATE**:
I managed to get cookie using answers, but when I call `finish()`, it returns to browser, not to activity, which called browser

**UPDATE 2**:
I updated the code, added flag, but the behaviour is same

Comment: How do you change the goToBrowser flag?

Comment: It depends on incoming `getIntent().getData()`

Comment: You need to debug and make sure it's updated correctly. I think you're not actually switching it to go in the other flow. Can you paste the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sniffer activity:

1: unregister the existing activity's intent filter from the current processing activity from AndroidManifest.xml (remove intent-filter data/scheme/host/path)

2: you could Create a new CookieSnifferActivity and register it into AndroidManifest.xml with exactly the same external intent filter (the data that you removed from the existing activity) e.g.:

```
<activity android:name=".my.package.CookieSnifferActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="example.com" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="cookie"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3: In your new CookieSnifferActivity's onCreate, you should now be able to read the cookie data:

```
    getIntent().getData().getPath()
```

4: In CookieSnifferActivity's onActivityResult(), forward the output result:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    setResult(resultCode)
    finish();
    //...
}
```

5: And finally you'd only want to forward the sniffed intent to the previously processing activity:

```
Intent forwarded = new Intent(getIntent());
forwarded.setClass(getPackageName(), "example.package.PreviousProcessingActivity");
startActivityForResult(forwarded, 0);
```

Comment: It didn't help. The issue is when I call `finish()` in my activity, it returns to browser, not in activity which called browser

Comment: Did you capture the cookie with the sniffer? Note that the proposed solution is just a sketch/idea and it may need slight changes to fit your exact need.

Comment: Yes, I can capture the cookie, but I cannot return to my app after that. I need to press "back" button

Comment: You could try to explicitly reorder the activity stack, eg. with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't help. I updated the code at the question. Can you look it?

Comment: I tried this in the new app and it helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood is that whenever you call `http://example.com/cookie`. it will redirect to `myapp://cookie=some_cookie` and you need the cookie from redirected url.Please let me know if i'm wrong in assuming the scenario. Here is the possible solution.

```
    WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
    webView.loadUrl("your url here");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            //Here you can get redirect url value and cookie from it.

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You understood correctly, but I need to get cookie from browser, not generate new one, so webview will not work here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. But if `myapp://cookie=some_cookie` is the deeplink to your app, then you can get the value of `cookie` param by following method

```
//onCreate function of activity which processes app schema
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getData() != null) {
      Uri data = getIntent().getData();
      //your cookie
      String cookie = data.getQueryParameter("cookie");
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, It's correct. But after calling `finish()` I'm returning to browser, not activity, which called browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something similar to Markus' answer, but with a different flag. Use a proxy activity to catch the app schema intent and extract the cookie there. Then start the original activity that launched the browser, passing the cookie as data in the Intent, and set the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag in the Intent.

This flag should clear any activities that were launched after the original activity, and your activity stack should be back to before you launched the browser, with the cookie passed to your original Activity as data.